# Does the event on CIA Created* have a one-time effect or last the duration of the turn?

Tags: twilight-struggle

The event on **CIA Created*** reads:

> The USSR reveals their hand of cards for this turn. The US may use the
>   Operations value of this card to conduct Operations.

Playing as the US, am I allowed to look at the USSR's hand anytime during the turn which this was played or only one time, when the card is played?

Comment: This is not authoritative, but, in ['The Pensky File' playthrough](http://youtu.be/nn4vlo6aC8g?t=1m45s) they say you can look whenever you want, for the rest of the turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mid War card **Lone Gunman*** has very similar text, but for the USSR:

> US Player reveals his hand. Then the USSR may Conduct Operations as if they played a 1 Op card.

To make it more confusing, consider the Late War card **Aldrich Ames Remix***, which reads [emphasis added]:

> US player exposes his hand to USSR *for remainder of turn*. USSR then chooses one card from US hand; this card is discarded.

This card is much more specific about the duration. This version of the card was first published with the deluxe edition, if the designers intended for the cards to operate the same, they could have made the text more similar.

Given **Aldrich Ames Remix***, for both **CIA Created*** and **Lone Gunman*** the cards are only revealed briefly.

---

The [Official FAQ](http://www.gmtgames.com/nnts/FAQv5.pdf) confirms this. Under **# 26 CIA Created**:

> Q. Does the USSR hand remain revealed for the entire turn? What happens if the USSR 
>   player gains new cards later in the turn?
>
> A. The effect of the card is not ongoing. The USSR only needs to reveal his hand at the 
>   time the CIA CREATED card is played.

On a subsequent question it goes on to say:

> This card and Lone Gunman (# 62) both work in the 
>   same manner.